# Как получить через ADO текст который выводится командой print?

Tags: sql-server, ado

Подробности:

1. Подключаюсь к **MS SQL Server 2012** с помощью объекта **ADODB.Connection**
2. Создаю объект **ADODB.Command**
3. Задаю тип команды и текст

   ```
   Command.CommandType = 1;
   Command.CommandText = "UPDATE [dbo].[PEOPLE] set [SEX] = 'M' WHERE [SEX] = 'F';
                          PRINT 'Обработано записей:'+ CAST(@@RowCount AS varchar(10));";
   ```
4. Выполняю команду

   ```
   Recordset = Command.Execute();
   ```

Вопрос: как получить текст который был выведен с помощью команды **PRINT**? и возможно ли его получить?

Answer (score 1):

Пример на C#:

```
ADODB.Command command = new ADODB.Command();
command.ActiveConnection = connection;
command.CommandText = @"
    select 1 as N
    union all
    select 2;

    print 'Recs:'+ CAST(@@RowCount AS varchar(10));
    print 'One more message';";

object recsAffected;
ADODB.Recordset data = command.Execute(out recsAffected);

while (data != null)
{
    foreach (ADODB.Error err in connection.Errors)
        Console.WriteLine(err.Description);

    data = data.NextRecordset(out recsAffected);
}
```